# postgresql : how to insert row into table that accepts four parameters

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.5

The following is a table that I have made:

\c alt_edu

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS child;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS parent;

CREATE TABLE parent
(
    p_id    CHAR(4),
    p_name  CHAR(8),
    --
    CONSTRAINT parent_PK PRIMARY KEY(p_id)
);

CREATE TABLE child
(
    c_id    CHAR(4),
    c_name  CHAR(8),
    p_id    CHAR(4),
    --
    CONSTRAINT child_PK PRIMARY KEY(c_id)
    -- , CONSTRAINT child_FK FOREIGN KEY(p_id) REFERENCES parent(p_id)
);


INSERT INTO parent(p_id, p_name)
VALUES  ( '100', 'Al' ),
        ( '200', 'Bob' ),
        ( '300', 'Chas' ),
        ( '400', 'Dale' ),
        ( '500', 'Eve' ),
        ( '600', 'Gwen' ),
        ( '700', 'Harry' );
        
INSERT INTO child(c_id, c_name, p_id)
VALUES  (   '1', 'Able', '100'),
        (   '2', 'Anne', '100'),
        (   '3', 'Debbie', '400'),
        (   '4', 'Connie', '300'),
        (   '5', 'Alicia', '100'),
        (   '6', 'Ed', '500'),
        (   '7', 'Xavier', '-13');
```

I now need to write a PGSQL procedure that will insert a row into child and accept four parameters The first parameter will be inserted into c_id, the second into c_name.The third will be inserted into p_id (the foreign key).  The fourth
is an INOUT parameter that is changed to reflect the error.
How would I go about writing this?

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post. If you can't get started, ask your instructor for help. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: Postgres 9.5 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  and it didn't support procedures to begin with - only functions.